# A sequential workflow appears to "ignore" its child activities

Tags: c#, .net, workflow-foundation

I'm using a hosted windows workflow sequential workflow.
When running the workflow, the child activities aren't activated.

- I tried setting breakpoints in the designer - they don't work
- Using a custom Tracking service to monitor execution of the workflow I see that the root workflow passes through these stages: 
  Created (workflow event)
  Started (workflow event)
  Executing (activity event of the workflow root)
  Closed (activity event of the workflow root)
  Completed (workflow event)

I also inspected the workflow object from the custom tracking service, and I saw that the root activity has an empty Activities collection

So although the workflow has child activities (they appear in the designer) - it appears that they "vanish" when I run the workflow.

Any ideas?

Ophir

Comment: 3.5 or 4?  If 4, rebuild your workflow from scratch.  The designer can get out of sync of the actual objects when you are modifying the code of the Activity while using them in workflows.

Comment: I'm using .Net 3.5
I did try to rebuild the solution several times.
I don't know if it matters, but the OS is Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Workaround:
I encountered the problem in a project that contained both the workflow and the host. 
I tried now separating them into different projects, and it appears to work.
I'm still looking for a "real" solution - partly because it's more convenient in our scenario to use a single solution, but mostly because I don't trust "voodoo" solutions for production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the problem in a project that contained both the workflow and the host. I tried now separating them into different projects, and it appears to work.